# ubuntu 20.10 on Macbook Pro late 2011 freezing at boot

Tags: macbook, boot-repair, 20.10, macbook-pro, nomodeset

I try to install ubuntu 20.10 on a Macbook Pro late 2011.
In this process, the default install option "Ubuntu" does not work:
I have to select "Ubuntu (Safe graphics)" from the initial menu. So I suspect some graphical driver issues. But I manage to complete the install process.
When I reboot for the first time after install completion, ubuntu freezes on a purple screen.

Comment: While the system is booting up, press the escape key in order to see issues. Please record them. I have had issues like this on other devices in the past, and I was able to see what they were and fix them by looking at and analyzing them.

Comment: Thank you. Pressing the escape key, the booting process gets stuck at: "A start job is running until boot process finishes up"

Comment: Interesting. When there is a start job like this running, it usually means that there is a program that is really sucking up everything. I would recommend entering Rescue Mode, finding the program, and disabling (deleting) it. Only try this if the boot says what it is. I would suggest watching the boot process, if you see a process that just stays running, or says it failed, you may have to reinstall Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

If you are having persistent issues on boot-up of your system, I would strongly recommend re-installing Ubuntu 20.10. You could probably fix that issue.

If you still have issues with boot up and if you think it is an issue with graphics, I would either get a new computer or replace the graphics stuff. Since Macs are supposed to be compact, I would either get a new computer or a new motherboard. It would be easier to get a new computer.

These may help:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TIXxlBt82AI

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tg4fWsFPzSE

Answer (score 0):

Under a live session from my USB install drive, I installed and ran boot-repair as explained on https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

I made sure to go in GRUB options and ticked "Add a kernel option" "nomodeset"

Then I rebooted and could run ubuntu without any problem